# MSSQL and EntityFramework - Storing and reading utc datetime

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, timezone-offset

I have a request to alter current columns which are type of 'time' and instead of capturing just time I need to capture so called "utc time".

My idea is to create a fixed codelist with all timezones, and then to reference it to a appropriate table as FK.

My questions are:

- Can column of a type 'time' hold also an information regarding time zones (utc, for example 15:00:00 +2 (gmt + 2)) and if not, could you suggest me another type for that column?
- Should I maybe need to separate it into two columns? For example: [15:00:00] - StartTime, [+2:00] - UtcOffset
- EF Insert: When I do inserting to the db, for that particular column, should I convert my `DateTime` object to for example `DateTimeOffset`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you just store UTC time in your column, wouldn't everything work? No need to store any timezone info because it's always UTC, and if you need to show something in certain time zone, just do it in the frontend?

Comment: Well, actually, I have some houses around the world, and each house has its own timezone. So basically, I need that offset information to store along with each house. So when I doan appointment/visit to that house from different timezone, I need to have in which timezone is my house, and then to save appointment in that timezone.

Comment: Yes, you need to have timezone for the **house**, not for the time. So when that house is in question, show the correct time in the frontend.

Comment: So basically, I came up with column StartTime `time` in mssql, and other `nvarchar` column names TimeZone. StartTime for example is `"12:00:00"` and TimeZone is `"+2:00"`. So how can I combine these two props in c# to get DateTimeOffset obj?

Comment: @JamesZ there are a *lot* of SO questions by people that assumed storing UTC would be enough. It's not, because offsets do change - twice a year. DST rules also change. You don't know what the timezone rules will be when you have to display the date. In the [Falsehoods programmers believe about time](https://gist.github.com/timvisee/fcda9bbdff88d45cc9061606b4b923ca) UTC appears twice, with the first fallacy the most important : `The local time offset (from UTC) will not change during office hours.`

Answer (score 4):

From the comments in your question, it sounds like you are building an appointment scheduling system.  I'll base my answer on that, because your specific questions aren't quite aligned to the scenario you described.

First, it's important to understand that the relationship between a *time zone* and an *offset* is a one-to-many relationship.  One time zone can have multiple offsets.  In other words, a time zone is not an offset, but rather a time zone *has* an offset.

- A time zone represents a geographic region where the local time is the same throughout.  It is identified by a string ID, such as `"America/Los_Angeles"` (an IANA time zone ID) or `"Pacific Standard Time"` (a Windows time zone ID).  In .NET, you will use them on the `TimeZoneInfo` object with the `Id` instance property or methods like `FindSystemTimeZonesById`.
- An offset is like `-07:00` or `+05:30` or even `+13:45`.  Any given offset applies only at a particular date and time.  For example, in `America/Los_Angeles`, either `-08:00` or `-07:00` apply depending on whether daylight saving time is in effect at a given point in time.  Keep in mind that DST is not the only reason for offsets to be different - many time zones have changed their *standard* time at some point in their history.

Also, it's called an offset because it is deviated from UTC by a certain amount. UTC itself always has a zero offset, delineated either by `+00:00` or sometimes by `Z`.  It's similar to GMT, except in how it is defined.  UTC applies universally, everywhere.  GMT technically applies only on the prime meridian.  They both refer to the zero offset.  You should prefer to say "UTC" in most cases.

Next, you should separate your application logic between future scheduling and present/past record keeping.

Present/past is the easier of the two.  Since the moment in time has actually occurred, the local time and its offset from UTC is fixed forever.  You can either store the local time and its offset in a single .NET `DateTimeOffset` structure (mapped to a `datetimeoffset` field in SQL Server).  In other words, you can simply store `2021-07-27T12:00:00-08:00`.

- Note that you could *instead* store the equivalent UTC date and time, which would be `2021-07-27T20:00:00+00:00`.  However you've then lost the local time, and thus would need to convert back using the original time zone if you wanted to see that time.  Some people prefer that, but I think it's more useful to store the original value.

For future scheduling, the situation is a bit different.  Consider that the offset might not be the same for one appointment as it will be for the next appointment in the same time zone.  Also consider that the definitions for which offset apply might *change* in between the time you schedule the appointment and when it comes around.  (The likelihood of that increases the further out you schedule.)

Thus, for each location you should not store an offset, but rather a time zone identifier.  Add a `TimeZoneId` to your object that stores each location (or each appointment depending on your model schema).  Use `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones` to list the available time zones.  The `DisplayName` property can be shown to your user, and the selected `Id` property gets assigned to the `TimeZoneId`.

Next you have to consider if you are scheduling a single appointment or creating a recurring appointment pattern.

- For a single appointment you simply need the *local* date and time for that appointment.  You can use a .NET `DateTime` struct (use `datetime2` in SQL).  Don't apply an offset, and don't convert to UTC.  Just store the information provided.
- For recurring appointments, you need to think through the information provided and store exactly what is given.  For example, if the appointment is at 10:00 every other Tuesday, you'll need to store "10:00", "Tuesdays" and "2 week intervals".  The data types for each will vary depending on how you choose to store and apply them.  For example, you might use a `time` type for 10:00, but you could store the other values using integers.  Appointments of different patterns could get stored in different ways.

  - Alternatively, some like to store patterns using a string containing a CRON expression.  You can google that for more details.

Now you have everything you need to both schedule an appointment and record that appointment after it happens.  But there's one part missing - you'll likely want some table of upcoming appointments that are easily queryable.  For that, you've got a few options:

- You can create a separate table via a background job of some kind.  Periodically it would query all the appointments, use their information to compute the next upcoming appointment time, and insert it.  You can store that in a `DateTimeOffset`, either as local time or as UTC.  (SQL Server will always compute indexes on the equivalent UTC time either way.)
- You could just add another field to your appointments that shows the next actual appointment time.  You can then compute the next upcoming appointment whenever the appointment is created or updated, or when that appointment occurs, and update the table accordingly.

With either approach keep in mind that you will want to periodically check for time zone data updates (either via Windows Update or keeping the `tzdata` package current on Linux).  You will also want to periodically re-compute future appointment times, in case that time zone data has been modified in a way that affects the appointments.

If all of this sounds super complicated - sorry, but it is.  Doing scheduling worldwide across time zones right is challenging.  If you want it simpler, you might want to look into a pre-made solution such as [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/), which you can integrate into your application.

Comment: Now if only we could persuade the SQL Server team to fully support IANA tzdb. (Come to think of it, have they announced any new features since 2019 ?)